# Cutting one line of the output of os.system and write that to a file

Tags: python

When I execute an `objdump` command in terminal, I get something like

```
$ objdump -d -M intel -S -z machine3.o

machine3.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <main>:
void main() {
   0:   55                      push   rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
   4:   00 00                   add    BYTE PTR [rax],al
   6:   00 00                   add    BYTE PTR [rax],al
```

And that continues.

I want to execute that command in a python script using `os.system("...")` and just extract and print the line that always start by `4:` to a txt file . How can I do that? Can I tell python to cut the 11th line of the output? or search for starting `4:` at the beginning of the line?

Comment: `$ objdump -d -M intel -S -z machine3.o | grep -e "^ *4:"`?

Comment: Yes, why not pipe to `grep`? Since you didn't include any Python code it doesn't seem like you strictly need a Python solution. Also do you want to grep the 11th line or the line that starts with `" *4:"`? That's not completely clear from your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of processing this with Python, most Linux systems have some useful processing tools for text strings. In fact most of these tools are commonly used to search through a stream of content for useful patterns.

## Printing the line(s) with `4:`

We can use [**`grep`** [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) for this:

```
objdump -d -M intel -S -z test.o | grep '^\s*4:'
```

If we are only interested in the first match, we can make use of the `-m` flag, like:

```
objdump -d -M intel -S -z test.o | grep '^\s*4:' -m 1
```

## Print lines up to (and including) `4:`

You can use [**`sed`** [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) for this. By writing `sed '/pattern/q'` you will print the content until (and including) the line where `pattern` is a match.

You thus could run the command:

```
objdump -d -M intel -S -z machine3.o | sed '/\s*4:/q'
```

Comment: I think `*4` also catches 14. Isn't it?

Comment: @mahmood: no, the `*` is a quantifier on the `\s`. `\s` is a spacing character. This is *not* a glob pattern, it is a regular expression.

Comment: `sed '/\s*4:/q'` prints everything and quits after print `4:` line. That is not correct.

Comment: @mahmood: well I specified two scenario's. The `grep` is used to match lines with `4:`. You can use `-m 1` to quit after the first match. The `sed` is, like the answer specifies, to match lines *up to* that line. So probably your use case requires to use `grep`.

Answer (score 2):

We could use subprocess's Popen method to extract the output and verify the line contains '4:', then write that line to our text file, this could do the trick :).

**Example**:

```
import subprocess

def main():

    """ Popen containining our objdump command """
    process = subprocess.Popen(['objdump', '-d', '-M', 'intel', '-S', '-z', 'machine3.o'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    """ Retrieve output or errors """
    out, err = process.communicate()

    """ Loop through our output """
    for line in out.splitlines():

        """ Check line contains our line-break 4: """
        if '4:' in line:

            """ Write line to our file """
            with open('somefile.txt', 'a') as the_file:
                the_file.write(line)

            """ End our for loop """
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Better to use [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run); and probably also better to check against a regex: `^ *4:`.

Comment: why iterating through all the lines if only a single line is of interest?